# Multiple content for filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**HTML**

```
<label>Store Category</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="campaign.store_category1" ng-checked="true" ng-true-value="'A'"> A 
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="campaign.store_category2" ng-true-value="'B'"> B
</label>
```

**Filter**

```
<tr ng-repeat="store in storeList | filter : {store_category:campaign.store_category1 || campaign.store_category2}">
```

Here I can filter store from store List. But here it only show one category of stores at atime. I need to show both stores from storeList, when both stores are slected.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a custom function to your `filter`, like so (see `myFilterFunction`)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlr">
        <label>Store Category</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="campaign.store_category1" ng-true-value="'A'"> A
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="campaign.store_category2" ng-true-value="'B'"> B
        </label>

        <div ng-repeat="store in storeList | filter : myFilterFunction ">{{ store.name }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ctrlr', function ($scope) {
        $scope.storeList = [
            { name: 'A1', store_category: 'A' },
            { name: 'A2', store_category: 'A' },
            { name: 'B1', store_category: 'B' },
            { name: 'B2', store_category: 'B' },
        ]

        $scope.campaign = {
            store_category1: 'A'
        }

        $scope.myFilterFunction = function (store) {
            return [$scope.campaign.store_category1, $scope.campaign.store_category2].indexOf(store.store_category) !== -1;
        }
    });
```